Create a mmap-able index of a tar to load in WASM
We want to load contents of a tar file in WASM using the emscripten VFS packaging format. Right now we convert the tar file on the server into a data and metadata files according to the above VFS packaging spec:

https://jeroen.r-universe.dev/bin/emscripten/contrib/4.4/jsonlite_1.8.9.js.metadata
https://jeroen.r-universe.dev/bin/emscripten/contrib/4.4/jsonlite_1.8.9.data

This works but is expensive on the server. I was wondering if instead of a data file we can send the tar file itself to the client, and generate the corresponding .js.metadata containing sizes and offsets of the files within the tar file itself.
Would this technically be possible with well-behaved tar files, or are the tar entries not necessarily contiguous blobs of data? We don't use tar extensions.
And is it possible to get the filename + position of entries in a tar file using command line tools? We can do tar -tvf file.tar to get the filenames, but afaict there is no documented option to get the offset and size of each entry.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/pax.html#tag_001_014_1700_006 ?

Ask emscripten to export the VFS API to the calling JS (-sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS). Then have the JS file load the tar file from the remote HTTP server and upload it to the internal memory filesystem using the FS API.
